# my Samsung note 3 not booting up

Tags: boot-loop, hardware, samsung-galaxy-note-3

Is my phone is bricked or not?The device is not turning on . I thought it was ran out of power. I connected it to my charger. But instead of charging, it shows a blinking  battery symbol contains a circle. When I turned off the charger, my phone started  flashing with the boot logo untill the end of its battery charge and it is not turning on. I'm not installed a custom rom or rooted it.Can anyone find a solution?

device:samsung galaxy note 3

model:SM-N900

Comment: What blink frequency have you seen? Is it a low frequency like one disappering every few seconds or a fast blinking like one per second?

Comment: logo shows more than two seconds and fading

Comment: Then the "flashing" may be the effect of a crash + bootloop of the "charge OS". If even this tine embedded system does not work without crash a serious hardware problem is with a high probability the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something got wrong with the power button of the phone. I removed it and turned it on without power button. It booted up normally. Thanks for Robert for mentioning about the hardware issue.